# On form inputs focus, show div. hide div on blur for multiple inputs and hidden divs

Tags: jquery, input, focus, hidden, blur

I have 2 text input fields that have a hidden div associated with each one.
When the client focuses in each text field the hidden div will appear. If the client clicks/focuses anywhere but the text field or the associated div they would both disappear (only 1 hidden div would be visible at a time).

I found a [working example snippet for a single text field input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426438/jquery-on-form-input-focus-show-div-hide-div-on-blur-with-a-caveat#answer-2427363) but I don't know how to adjust the script for two separate inputs/divs.

**1)** Focus in "Search Markets" shows "Select markets" div (dark area click will close/hide the div).
[image]

**2)** Focus in "Search Symbols" shows "Select symbols" div (dark area click will close/hide the div).
[image]

```js
//BASED OFF SO SINGULAR EXAMPLE
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426438/jquery-on-form-input-focus-show-div-hide-div-on-blur-with-a-caveat#answer-2427363


$('#search-markets').focus(function() {
    $('div.select-filters').css('display', 'flex');
    $(document).bind('focusin.select-filters click.select-filters',function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest('.select-filters, #search-markets').length) return;
        $(document).unbind('.select-filters');
        $('div.select-filters').slideUp(300);
    });
});
$('div.select-filters').hide();
```

```css
#select-data-inputs {
    background-color: #000;
}

.select-filters {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
}

#select-symbols {
    background-color: rgba(1, 56, 89, 0.85);
}

#select-markets {
    background-color: rgba(2, 104, 165, 0.85);
}

.filter-list li.list-inline-item {
    width: 48%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">



    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row m-5 ">
            <div class="col-12 text-center">
                <h1>On form inputs focus, show div. hide div on blur for <span class="text-danger">multiple inputs</span> and hidden divs</h1>
                <p class="lead"><i><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426438/jquery-on-form-input-focus-show-div-hide-div-on-blur-with-a-caveat" target="_blank">Based from SO sigular example</a></i></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="row">
            <!--TEXT FIELDS INPUT ROW-->
            <!--TEXT FIELDS INPUT ROW-->
            <div id="select-data-inputs" class="controls form-row p-3 w-100">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <input type="text" id="search-markets" class="input form-control" placeholder="Search Markets">
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 offset-1">
                    <input type="text" id="search-symbols" class="input form-control" placeholder="Search Symbols">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main-display">
            <!--HIDDEN DIV FOR FIRST TEXT FIELD-->
            <!--HIDDEN DIV FOR FIRST TEXT FIELD-->
            <div id="select-markets" class="row select-filters p-4">
                <div class="select-heading col-12 pl-2">
                    <h6 class="small-sub-heading">Select markets</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 pt-2 select-filter-items">
                    <ul class="filter-list list-unstyled pl-2">
                        <li class="list-inline-item"> 
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="market-option-1" value="market-option-1">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="market-option-1">Market Option 1</label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"> 
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="market-option-2" value="market-option-2">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="market-option-2">Market Option 2</label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"> 
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="market-option-3" value="market-option-3">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="market-option-3">Market-Option 3</label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"> 
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="market-option-4" value="market-option-4">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="market-option-4">Market-Option 4</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--HIDDEN DIV FOR SECOND TEXT FIELD-->
            <!--HIDDEN DIV FOR SECOND TEXT FIELD-->
            <div id="select-symbols" class="row select-filters p-4">
                <div class="select-heading col-4 offset-5 pl-2">
                    <h6 class="small-sub-heading">Select symbols</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 offset-5 pt-2 select-filter-items">
                    <ul class="filter-list list-unstyled pl-2">
                        <li class="list-inline-item"> 
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="symbol-option-1" value="symbol-option-1">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="symbol-option-1">Symbol Option 1</label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"> 
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="symbol-option-2" value="symbol-option-2">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="symbol-option-2">Symbol Option 2</label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"> 
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="symbol-option-3" value="symbol-option-3">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="symbol-option-3">Symbol Option 3</label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"> 
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="symbol-option-4" value="symbol-option-4">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="symbol-option-4">Symbol Option 4</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pjaaA8dDz/5BgdFUPX6M/9SUZv4d12SUPF0axWc+VRZkx5xU3daN+lYb49+Ax+Tl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose something like this is what you want:

```js
//BASED OFF SO SINGULAR EXAMPLE
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426438/jquery-on-form-input-focus-show-div-hide-div-on-blur-with-a-caveat#answer-2427363


$('#search-markets').focus(function() {
    $('div.select-filters.market').css('display', 'flex');
    $(document).bind('focusin.select-filters.market click.select-filters.market',function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest('.select-filters.market, #search-markets').length) return;
        $(document).unbind('.select-filters.market');
        $('div.select-filters.market').slideUp(300);
    });
});

$('#search-symbols').focus(function() {
    $('div.select-filters.symbol').css('display', 'flex');
    $(document).bind('focusin.select-filters.symbol click.select-filters.symbol',function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest('.select-filters.symbol, #search-symbols').length) return;
        $(document).unbind('.select-filters.symbol');
        $('div.select-filters.symbol').slideUp(300);
    });
});
$('div.select-filters').hide();
```

```css
#select-data-inputs {
    background-color: #000;
}

.select-filters {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
}

#select-symbols {
    background-color: rgba(1, 56, 89, 0.85);
}

#select-markets {
    background-color: rgba(2, 104, 165, 0.85);
}

.filter-list li.list-inline-item {
    width: 48%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">



    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row m-5 ">
            <div class="col-12 text-center">
                <h1>On form inputs focus, show div. hide div on blur for <span class="text-danger">multiple inputs</span> and hidden divs</h1>
                <p class="lead"><i><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426438/jquery-on-form-input-focus-show-div-hide-div-on-blur-with-a-caveat" target="_blank">Based from SO sigular example</a></i></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="row">
            <!--TEXT FIELDS INPUT ROW-->
            <!--TEXT FIELDS INPUT ROW-->
            <div id="select-data-inputs" class="controls form-row p-3 w-100">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <input type="text" id="search-markets" class="input form-control" placeholder="Search Markets">
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 offset-1">
                    <input type="text" id="search-symbols" class="input form-control" placeholder="Search Symbols">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main-display">
            <!--HIDDEN DIV FOR FIRST TEXT FIELD-->
            <!--HIDDEN DIV FOR FIRST TEXT FIELD-->
            <div id="select-markets" class="row select-filters market p-4">
                <div class="select-heading col-12 pl-2">
                    <h6 class="small-sub-heading">Select markets</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 pt-2 select-filter-items">
                    <ul class="filter-list list-unstyled pl-2">
                        <li class="list-inline-item"> 
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="market-option-1" value="market-option-1">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="market-option-1">Market Option 1</label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"> 
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="market-option-2" value="market-option-2">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="market-option-2">Market Option 2</label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"> 
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="market-option-3" value="market-option-3">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="market-option-3">Market-Option 3</label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"> 
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="market-option-4" value="market-option-4">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="market-option-4">Market-Option 4</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--HIDDEN DIV FOR SECOND TEXT FIELD-->
            <!--HIDDEN DIV FOR SECOND TEXT FIELD-->
            <div id="select-symbols" class="row select-filters symbol p-4">
                <div class="select-heading col-4 offset-5 pl-2">
                    <h6 class="small-sub-heading">Select symbols</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 offset-5 pt-2 select-filter-items">
                    <ul class="filter-list list-unstyled pl-2">
                        <li class="list-inline-item"> 
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="symbol-option-1" value="symbol-option-1">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="symbol-option-1">Symbol Option 1</label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"> 
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="symbol-option-2" value="symbol-option-2">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="symbol-option-2">Symbol Option 2</label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"> 
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="symbol-option-3" value="symbol-option-3">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="symbol-option-3">Symbol Option 3</label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"> 
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="symbol-option-4" value="symbol-option-4">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="symbol-option-4">Symbol Option 4</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pjaaA8dDz/5BgdFUPX6M/9SUZv4d12SUPF0axWc+VRZkx5xU3daN+lYb49+Ax+Tl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You need to split the class between symbols and markets (`.select-filters`).
Notice that I use add `select-filters`**`market`** for market and `select-filters`**`symbol`** for symbol.

For separating the focus you need to use a specified function like `div.select-filters.market` for market and `div.select-filters.symbol` for symbol:

```
$('#search-markets').focus(function() {
    $('div.select-filters.market').css('display', 'flex');
    $(document).bind('focusin.select-filters.market click.select-filters.market',function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest('.select-filters.market, #search-markets').length) return;
        $(document).unbind('.select-filters.market');
        $('div.select-filters.market').slideUp(300);
    });
});

$('#search-symbols').focus(function() {
    $('div.select-filters.symbol').css('display', 'flex');
    $(document).bind('focusin.select-filters.symbol click.select-filters.symbol',function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest('.select-filters.symbol, #search-symbols').length) return;
        $(document).unbind('.select-filters.symbol');
        $('div.select-filters.symbol').slideUp(300);
    });
});
$('div.select-filters').hide();
```

Comment: Yeah that works thanks but it looks like a lot of duplicated code. Could that be refactored or improved?

Comment: @Kerry7777 I think we could remove the `select-filters2` for div.select-filters. And add a custom class like `market` and `symbol`. But for the javascript function, I think it's better to have a specified one.

Comment: @Kerry7777 For more idea about code refactoring and improvement, it might be a good idea to ask [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Thanks man, I didn't know about https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: I asked the question for a refactored / improved script as suggested at Stack Exchange Code Review:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/212253/on-form-inputs-focus-show-div-hide-div-on-blur-for-multiple-inputs-and-hidden#212254